# How to customize a theme?

Tags: add-theme-support

I've created a theme where I use each page title as an ID of a `<div>`, and for each div I put a background with CSS. Now I want to add some extra features to my theme and give the possibility for users to choose their pics.

I've tried with this:

```
add_theme_support('');
```

but I don't know where to start. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you looked at the codex?? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, don't ask opinion based questions on StackOverflow.
- Secondly, try Googling for an answer

---

You can try the WordPress Theme Customizer, check out the docs:

- [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)

Here is what it looks like

[image]

Basically you need to register Sections (stores a set of options). Then you need to register Settings (to store the value of each option) and Controls (a *form* for users to change the options)

To start of, create a function and use the hook `customize-register`

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

You can add a section like so:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'your_section_id' , array(
    'title'      => __( 'Visible Section Name', 'mytheme' ),
    'priority'   => 30, // To control the order it appears in
) );
```

You can add a setting like so:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'your_setting_id' , array(
    'default'     => '#000000',
) );
```

And a control like so:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
    'label'        => __( 'Header Color', 'mytheme' ),
    'section'    => 'your_section_id',
    'settings'   => 'your_setting_id',
) ) );
```

If you add the code for the sections, settings and controls inside your function, and put that inside your `functions.php` file. Then, in `wp-admin.php`, hover over *Appearance* and click *Customize*. Your section and control will be in there for you to change.

To get your setting, use the following code in your theme files:

```
<?php echo get_theme_mod('your_setting_id') ?>
```

This will echo the value of the setting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you , know i have an idea where to start thank you

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (press the tick underneath the voting buttons)